# How can i stop QT Widget from closing?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qmainwindow

I have a class (Window) that inherits from QWidget (Not QMainWindow).
This is the important part of my main function.

```
 QApplication app (argc, argv);

 QMainWindow *window = new QMainWindow;

 QMenuBar *tool_bar = new QMenuBar (window);

 Window *graph_area = new Window (arguments);

 window->setMenuBar (tool_bar);
 window->setCentralWidget (graph_area);
 window->show ();
 app.exec ();
```

I thought that i would just override "closeEvent", but for some reason it doesn't get called when pressing the closing button.

I want to stop the user from closing the application if some process is still working.

Any ideas about how i might achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **either**:

1. Subclass `QMainWindow`, instead of `QWidget`
2. Override `QMainWindow::closeEvent`, instead of `QWidget::closeEvent`
3. Allocate your `QMainWindow` subclass on the stack, instead of on the heap, i.e.:

   ```
    MyMainWindowSubclass window;
   ```

**or**:

Change your code to:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);

Window w;

window->show();

app.exec();
```

and `Window::closeEvent` will be called.

Answer (score 1):

Make your Window class an event filter and install it on the main window object. You’ll reimplement `filterEvent` method in Window. Do not forget to install it on the main window! And make sure that the filter filters the event out - the boolean result indicates whether you let the result through or filter it out. Look up the exact value needed to indicate either one - it’s a bad api and I never remember whether true or false does what I intend. It’s a classical case where an enumeration return value would work better, like `Qt::Accept`/`Qt::Reject` or some such.

Answer (score -1):

I actually found another solution to my problem, that I find more pleasant. I can create a custom class mainwindow that inherits from QMainWindow and use it instead of QMainWindow. It might be more appropriate, because I will probably need some other changes to QMainWindow as well.